# Alexa smarthome skill routines

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-smart-home-skill

I need to create an Alexa smart home skill. I would like to control my lights using Alexa device. But based on my understanding, smart home skill only support utterances like this

```
Alexa, turn on name
Alexa, turn off name
Alexa, set name to x percent
Alexa, brighten name
Alexa, dim name
Alexa, dim name by x percent
Alexa, brighten name by x percent
Alexa, set name to x degrees
Alexa, decrease name by x degrees
Alexa, increase name by x degrees
Alexa, decrease name
```

But, my use cases is little different.

```
Alexa, turn on the kitchen light.
Alexa, dim the bedrromlight to 50%
Alexa, turn on the halllight for 3 hours
Alexa, set a daily timer for the testlight to turn on every day at 9am
Alexa, how dim is the bedrromlight right now?
```

Is smart home skill is suited for my use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine today with a Smart Home Skill:

```
Alexa, turn on the kitchen light.
Alexa, dim the bedroomlight to 50 %.
```

You can use a routine for this (but Routine's can't currently be created using voice, only in the companion app):

```
Alexa, set a daily timer for the testlight to turn on every day at 9am
```

These are not currently supported by Alexa:

```
Alexa, how dim is the bedroomlight right now?
Alexa, turn on the halllight for 3 hours.
```

You *could* build a Custom Skill for these two use cases, or simply wait for Amazon to implement them. If it were me, I'd focus on the core use cases that already work using a Smart Home Skill and not waste time on a Custom Skill. You can't integrate Custom Skill stuff with Routines, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not only related to the specific Smart Home Skill. The user could give the different located devices (f.e. your lights) names like `kitchen light` and he could assign the different Smart Home devices to rooms.

Further more the user is also able to create groups with several devices in it so you could say:

```
Alexa, turn on the kitchen
```

and all related lights will switch on.

The user is also able to create routines in the Alexa app in your case:

```
switch the testlight on at 9 am every day.
```

This could probably not be done by voice but in the app.

So Alexa Smart Home should be fine for use case.